# Why strace -f can't trace the child progress after |?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, system-calls, strace

I am trying to see what would happen about system call when I running one command, but it seems those command after | can't be shown? like:

```
strace -f cat a.txt| cat
```

It seems strace and -f perimeter can show the whole process. I think the last part is in the child progress created by fork. Why and how to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `strace` manual (emphasis mine).

> -f          Trace child processes as they are  created  by
>               **currently  traced processes** as a result of the fork(2),
>               vfork(2) and clone(2) system calls.

The traced process in your case is the first `cat` process. The second `cat` process is *not* a child of the first `cat` process. The fork is done by the shell.

One way to achieve what you want is to trace the shell:

```
strace -f bash -c "cat a.txt| cat"
```

Comment: Sorry, I should use `cat` not `cats`. (you can update it to make your answer perfect) Now I use your sentence (replace cats with cat). I still can't see the fork() command in the output, do you know why?

Comment: The bash shell uses `clone` not `fork`. Look for that instead.

Comment: Oh, you are fabulous!